# Mathematica HDF5 and compound arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, wolfram-mathematica, hdf5

Does anybody have a workaround in Mathematica for reading HDF5 compound arrays? I have a simple 2D compound type (int/float) in a table but it is currently ignored.

An example HDF5 type might be:

```
DATATYPE H5T_COMPOUND {
    H5T_IEEE_F32LE "X";
    H5T_IEEE_F32LE "Y";
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your data structure?

Comment: Also please note that as per the help (although not very clear) you can only specify "DataFormat" at the Dataset level.

Comment: Edited to include a HDF5 type.

Comment: Came across the following.  It is old, and you possibly know about it. http://thedailyreviewer.com/compsys/view/hdf5-broken-in-v7-10897059 .  Seemingly OK in v6? Is the bug still present in v8?

Comment: I haven't duplicated this bug - but thanks. The problem is that Mathematica explicitly cannot import compound types.

Answer (score 4):

There is a package, apparently created by Scot Martin [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/contrib/mathematica/).

As far as I can see, it implements a lot of the HDF5 functionality, including Compound Types.

Here is a brief snippet from `11 HDF5HighLevel Examples.nb` in the package:

```
With[
 {
  file = FileNameJoin[{Directory[], subfolderWithExamples, "h5ex_t_cmpd.h5"}],
  dataSet = "DS1"
  },
 CompoundDataType`Information[file, dataSet]
 ]
(*
{"DataSpaceDimensions" -> {4}, 
 "MemberDataTypeClass" -> {0, -3, 1, 1},  
 "MemberMemorySize" -> {8, 8, 8, 8}, 
 "MemberName" -> {"Serial number"  , "Location", 
                  "Temperature (F)", "Pressure (inHg)"},  
 "MemberOffset" -> {0, 8, 20, 28}, 
 "MemberSize" -> {8, 8, 8, 8}, 
 "MemoryDataTypeSize" -> 32, 
 "NumberOfMembers" -> 4}
*)
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

It [appears](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HDF5.html) that version 8 still ignores compound data types.  However, as of v. 8, an alternative may be to create an [Import Converter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) that can load in compound data types.  This may mean you will have to implement the HDF5 importer all over again, but I haven't tried it.  I am still using 7, but I've wanted this type of functionality for a long time.

Comment: If someone writes an Importer Converter, pleeease share!

Answer (score 1):

I have created `h5dumpImport`, an open source *Mathematica* Package that provides a platform independent way to import HDF5 (.h5) file's datasets with compound datatypes while hiding much of the HDF5 implementation from the user.  The package with documentation, examples, and unit test is located [here](https://github.com/m2orris/h5dumpImport).

Currently, the `h5dumpImport` package does not directly import the HDF5 (.h5) file format. The `h5dumpImport` package imports an ASCII dump of a dataset generated by the `h5dump` command line tool.

Source code and pre-built binary distributions of the HDF5 Software which includes the `h5dump` command line tool can be found at the The HDF Group's [website](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html#obtain).

### Basic Example

```
Needs["h5dumpImport`"]
datasets = Import["testData.h5", {"Datasets"}];
dumpFile = h5dump["/usr/bin/h5dump", "testData.h5", datasets[[1]]];
dumpImport = h5dumpImportNew[h5dumpImport[], dumpFile];
dumpImport.h5dumpImportData[All]
dumpImport.h5dumpImportClose[];
```

---

Results:

```
{{1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 111111, 1111111, 1.1, 11.11, "one"},
 {2, 22, 222, 2222, 22222, 222222, 2222222, 2.2, 22.22, "two"},
 {3, 33, 333, 3333, 33333, 333333, 3333333, 3.3, 33.33, "three"}}
```

### Detailed installation instructions, usage information, and documentation, examples, and unit tests can be found [here](https://github.com/m2orris/h5dumpImport).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version **11.1** Import of HDF5 files can handle compound types (even nested) and they are translated to Associations.

A sample file `ExampleData/sample2.h5` contains a dataset named `/Compound` with a 2x2 matrix of compound elements. You can import the data like this:

```
In[3]:= Import["ExampleData/sample2.h5", "/Compound"]

Out[3]= {
  {
    <|
      "Country" -> "Botswana", 
      "Military" -> {5.3, 4.5}, 
      "Elevation" -> <|"Max" -> 4892, "Min" -> 513, "Highest point" -> "Otse Hill"|>
    |>,
    <|
      "Country" -> "Chile", 
      "Military" -> {8.8, 3.7}, 
      "Elevation" -> <|"Max" -> 6893, "Min" -> 0, "Highest point" -> "Ojos del Salado"|>
    |>
  }, {
    <|
      "Country" -> "France", 
      "Military" -> {5.3, 3.3}, 
      "Elevation" -> <|"Max" -> 4810, "Min" -> -10, "Highest point" -> "Mont Blanc"|>
    |>, 
    <|
      "Country" -> "Laos", 
      "Military" -> {18.9, 4.3}, 
      "Elevation" -> <|"Max" -> 2817, "Min" -> 70, "Highest point" -> "Phou Bia"
    |>
  |>
}}
```

To learn more about the compound datatype for specific dataset, you may examine the `DataFormat` element:

```
In[2]:= Import["ExampleData/sample2.h5", {"DataFormat", "/Compound"}]

Out[2]= <|
  "Class" -> "Compound", 
  "Structure" -> <|
    "Country" -> "String", 
    "Military" -> <|"Class" -> "Array", "Dimensions" -> {2}, "DataFormat" -> "Real64"|>, 
    "Elevation" -> <|
      "Class" -> "Compound", 
      "Structure" -> <|"Max" -> "Integer16", "Min" -> "Integer16", "Highest point" -> "String"|>
    |>
  |>
|>
```